# Импорт JS для страниц отдельно

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет! Имеется такая структура:

**header:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>

<body>
```

**footer:**

```
<div class="footer-text">Footer text</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**page1:**

```
import header
   <div class="blah-blah">page1</div>
import footer
```

**page2:**

```
import header
   <div class="blah-blah">page2</div>
import footer
```

и 2 js файла `forPage1.js`, `forPage2.js`, которые полезны для соответствующих страниц: `page1` и `page2`

Как лучше всего подключить скрипты? Я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Подключить скрипты для каждой страницы отдельно (т.е. `forPage1.js` для `page1`). Но для этого придется перенести jQuery (или какие-то другие библиотеки) в header. Но кажется это плохо влияет на производительность.
2. Подключить все в footer. Тут получается для каждой страницы будут подгружаться все скрипты.

Может есть уже какие-то практики для подключения скриптов по необходимости?

Comment: А не надо разделять страницу на header и footer, надо завести шаблон base.html и уже его наследовать, переопределяя указанные в нём блоки, включая блок со скриптами, и проблема решится сама собой. Только вот подозреваю, ни о каком шаблонизаторе речи тут не идёт?

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, я вас понял. Об этом совсем не подумал. Шаблонизатор есть - JSP (просто не хотел вопрос привязывать к конкретной технологии). Сейчас буду гуглить, как это делается в JSP.